# Chrome and XPCOM

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xpcom

Вoes Chrome have an equivalent to XPCOM?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. Extensions and plugins can only interact with the browser through their respective APIs.

Answer (score 1):

No. Mozilla implements its many fundamental components (browser, network, string, window, etc) libraries in XPCOM such that C++ and JavaScript can re-use, invoke, and override those APIs. Therefore many firefox addons can take advantages of this and build powerful features in JavaScript with XPCOM.

However, in Chrome or WebKit, there is no such equivilant components. Their extensions can only call their browser built-in APIs.