# How to use java class and it's attributes inside a javascript code

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write an extension to google chrome and I want to use my own java classes and it's attributes, methods inside a javascript code. I search on the internet but I did'nt find enough resources in terms of implementation. Can you give me any idea how to integrate and use my own java classes inside a javascript code. If you can help me , I will appreciate

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only instance variables of your classes, you would do well by converting your object into JSON and sending it to you extension. Check http://www.json.org/java/index.html. As pointed out by Marcelo, GWT will help you but only if you are deploying your app on Google App Engine. It is not for chrome extensions.

Comment: App Engine or any other server, really. It's just an UI technology, the whole server part extends standard servlets.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. Both are totally different programming languages. Javascript is a script that is interpreted by the web browser. Java is a object oriented programming language that needs to be compiled and run in a virtual machine (JVM). Many people are confused by the similar names.

Comment: But I know that there are implementations about it.Isn't there any way to reach java code from javascript ?

Comment: You can use Java-JavaScript interaction libraries or getting use of JSON, JSObject etc.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't [Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) what you are looking for? It translates code written in Java to native Javascript to be run on the browser.

I wonder if it would be possible to integrate the generated code with your code, to run it as a browser extension, though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted a bean like access from a scripting language to java 'objects'..

http://commons.apache.org/bsf/  may help you to access Java objects and methods from scripting languages. 
 it claims to support javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has something like this through XP-COM.

also: see this, [Chrome and XPCOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814700/chrome-and-xpcom)

I am wondering if you found a solution to this.